# Javascript .filter() -> cannot read property 'X' of null

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

is there a better way to write this line?

```js
var tracks = responseJSON.items.map((item) => item.track).filter((item) => item.preview_url != null)
```

I often get this error:  `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'preview_url' of null"`

I imagine it occurs because `.map()` returned an empty array, but if that were the case, wouldn't `filter()` merely do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the track is sometimes `null`, so filter out items with no tracks before trying to access a property of it, which can be done concisely with optional chaining:

```
const tracks = responseJSON.items
  .map(item => item.track)
  .filter(item => item?.preview_url != null);
```

Or:

```
const tracks = responseJSON.items
  .map(item => item.track)
  .filter(item => item && item.preview_url != null);
```

Comment: Wow! As an iOS Developer! Thrilled to learn JS has optional chaining! I was feeling spoiled by Swift

Answer (score 1):

Just test that `item` and `item.preview_url` are not null.

`var tracks = responseJSON.items.map(item => item.track).filter(item => item != null && item.preview_url != null)`